# Java switch runs all cases if no break

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm confused about this example. If `break` is deleted then both `Today is Saturday` and `Today is Sunday` will be printed. I would like to know why this happens.

```
int day = 4;
switch (day) {
  case 4:
    System.out.println("Today is Saturday");
   // break;
  case 7:
    System.out.println("Today is Sunday");
   // break;
 
}
```

---

P.S: to those who are surprised why I asked such a simple question:
Its been a while, I am learning [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), that does not need to add breaks in the `when` expression, so it made me confused when Ii was working on a Java project that needs breaks in a `switch` statement.

Comment: Without being too snide, read up on how the language works?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html -> "_The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered._"

Comment: If you don't break out of the switch, the first matching case and all below cases are executed (until the first break). You can use the -> instead of : in newer java versions, which makes sure only one case is executed.

Comment: The same is also true in many (most?) other languages. According to your profile, I guess you are most familiar with [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php): "If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.". So I'm a bit surprised that this surprises you.

Comment: TLDR; Thats how switch statements in Java work.  Like most languages that share a heritage with C Java allows the cases in Switch statements to "fall through" to the next case if the case statement isint ended with a break statement.  This can be useful, though can also lead to bugs.  Java 12 introduced a Switch expression that has slightly different syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is probably a duplicate of something else, but the reason is that `case` statement within a Java `switch` by default will flow onto the next `case` statement unless a `break` be explicitly mentioned.  To better understand *why* the case statements behave this way, an example would make this clear.  Let's say that you wanted the same logic to happen for Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday.  Then, you could use the following:

```java
switch (day) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Today is Monday, Tuesday, or Wednesday");
        break;

    case 4:
        System.out.println("Today is Thursday");
        break;

    case 7:
        System.out.println("Today is Sunday");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Break statement:** Break statement is used to terminate the loop. When a break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is
> immediately terminated.

Therefore, when we use the **break** statement inside the **switch** statement, it terminates the loop at that case, and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.

**Answer to your Question:** When the **break** statement is not used, the control of the program flows through each and every case until either it reaches the end of the **switch** block or a **break** statement is encountered.